# create table in hbase shell : unintialized constant

Tags: hbase

Simple question, I want to create table like below, could you tell me why this command is not working?

```
hbase(main):004:0> create 'test', {NAME => 'test', INDEX => 'test'}
NameError: uninitialized constant INDEX
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? this error remains same even if i declare 'create table' explicitly

Comment: hbase(main):005:0> create table 'test', {NAME => 'test', INDEX => 'test'}
NameError: uninitialized constant INDEX

hbase(main):006:0>

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with `INDEX => 'test'`? As far as I know that property does not exists:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell

```
 create    Create table; pass table name, a dictionary of specifications per
           column family, and optionally a dictionary of table configuration.
           Dictionaries are described below in the GENERAL NOTES section.
           Examples:

           hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
           hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
           hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
           hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
           hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, \
             BLOCKCACHE => true}
```

Just do a `create 'test', 'test'` or `create 'test', {NAME => 'test'}`